# I can't figure out what NVIDIA GPU I have , I get multiple names?

Tags: nvidia, gpu-driver

I get the following output:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep '\[03'
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] [10de:1140] (rev a1)
```

Now I can't figure out which GPU do I have, and what driver to install.

Comment: What does `sudo lshw -C display` return? `ubuntu-drivers` can be used to show applicable packages for your system.

Comment: `sudo lshw -C` returns the same thing detailed ,  along with my intel gpu .

Comment: Did you check the information provided by your BIOS? There should also be something about the installed GPU.